# Photoshop - show the same file in two separate windows, each different layer comp

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is it possible to show the same photoshop file in two separate windows, each with a different layer comp?

Comment: Only if you duplicate the psd file and open it twice. What's the scenario? Why do you want that? There could be a workaround or an alternative.

Comment: i like showing different layer comps side by side - it's often 70-90% the same file with different variations

Comment: I don't know if I'm immediately thinking too complicated, but I think it would be possible to make a script that duplicates the full document for each layer comp or just the selected comps and merges them all into a separate document with all the chosen layer comps side by side.

Comment: You could use `File > Export > Layer Comps to files` (or to PDF) Doesn't make it as easy as a new window for the same document, but may be easier than duplicating the entire document.

Comment: That requires creating new files each time though... Would there be a better totally different way to do this to compare side by side different versions (saved as layer comps or otherwise) of a similar file?

Comment: Scott's suggestion is the best you can do with what is built-in. It's also possible someone has already made a script for this  exact purpose, but I doubt it. Making your own script the way I described is the best you can do. The script could literally work like this: you run the script and a new PS doc opens with the selected layer comps side by side in that one document. The only downside I foresee is if your document is a little hefty, it can take a while for the script to finish. Of course creating your own script takes some effort...

Comment: A general question is what do people use to compare layer comps side by side?

Comment: They export them as files. After that it kinda depends on what kinda comparison is needed. They might print it ina specific way... Or run them through a diff tool... Or just leave as is...

Comment: what do you use for diff in such a case

Comment: That was more on the maybe side of things. While I do use Kaleidoscope sometimes for image files, I can't say I've ever gone straight from PS comps to Kaleidoscope. Not sure why you'd need a diff tool for something you have in PS as comps, but something like these apps is what I meant: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/80348/2332

Comment: a really common thing for diffs is one would have a different layer adjustment or just one missing item. it helps sometimes to look at them side by side - or ideally 4x4 and other arrangements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I wrote a script that should get pretty close to what you are after.

If you're not familiar with using scripts, I'm sure there are many sources if you google: "how to run scripts in photoshop" or something. Though it may be good to know that you can: 1. set a shortcut to run a script 2. run a script from an Action 3. run it from the `File > Scripts...` menu 4. run it using third party applications (like I'm doing in the gif). The script was tested in Photoshop CC 2019, so there is a chance it won't work in anything older...

> What you don't see in the gif is that this comparison image is actually a new document. I just keep closing it and running the script again. The gif is a bit hectic, I know, but I had to make sure the filesize is small enough to upload here.

[image]

```
// Version 1.1.
// Compare Selected Comps.jsx
// https://gist.github.com/joonaspaakko/adbe208a867f8681afa86032f91f5099?ts=2

// #########
// Changelog
// #########

// v.1.1.
// - Tested in Photoshop CC 2019
// - Added a fallback for when less than 2 layer comps are selected, in which case all layer comps are pushed to the comparison document.
// - Fixed the border issue.
// - Fixed the issue where comp gets fused with the comparison document background.

// v.1.0.
// - First Version
// - Tested in Photoshop CC 2019
// - Known issues:
//      - The script adds a border around the final comp layer in order to divide the comp layers a bit. If the comp doesn't have a solid background, the stroke will do weird things.
//      - The first comp gets fused with the background of the comparison document in some situations...

#target photoshop

var startCompare = false;
var maxHorizontal = 1;

if ( app.documents.length > 0 ) init();

function init() {

    var rulerUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnits;
    app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;

    var doc = app.activeDocument;

    // Duplicate current document
    var tempDoc = doc.duplicate( (doc.name + ' (Comparison)') );

    // Check layer comp selection.length
    // Get layer comps
    var layerComps = tempDoc.layerComps;
    var selectedComps = [];
    var leftOverComps = [];
    // Go through every comp
    for ( var i=0; i < layerComps.length; i++ ) {
        var comp = layerComps[ i ];
        // If comp is selected...
        if ( comp.selected ) {
            selectedComps.push( comp );
        }
        else {
            leftOverComps.push( comp );
        }
    }

    // If more than one comp is selected...
    // Remove all leftover layer comps
    if ( selectedComps.length > 1 ) {

        // Go through every comp
        for ( var i=0; i < leftOverComps.length; i++ ) {
            var comp = leftOverComps[ i ];
            comp.remove();
        }

    }

    dialog( tempDoc.layerComps.length );

    if ( !startCompare ) {
    // tempDoc.close( SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES );
    }
    else if ( startCompare ) {

        var tempDocsCollection = [];
        // Get layer comps again...
        var layerComps = tempDoc.layerComps;
        var selectedCompsLength = layerComps.length;
        // Go through every comp
        for ( var i=0; i < selectedCompsLength; i++ ) {

            var comp = layerComps[ i ];
            comp.apply();
            var thisCompDoc = tempDoc.duplicate( comp.name, true);
            thisCompDoc.flatten();
            addBlackBorder();
            tempDocsCollection.push( thisCompDoc );
            app.activeDocument = tempDoc;

        }

        // Get ready to receive compsies
        // Scrub the temp document clean...
        tempDoc.flatten();
        whiteFill();

        // New size to fit the border
        tempDoc.resizeCanvas( (tempDoc.width + 1), (tempDoc.height + 1), AnchorPosition.TOPLEFT );

        var tempDocWidth = tempDoc.width;
        var tempDocHeight = tempDoc.height;

        // Find out how many rows are needed
        var columns = maxHorizontal;
        var rows = 0;
        var equalizer = 1;
        for ( var i = 0; i < selectedCompsLength; i++ ) {
            if ( equalizer == 1 ) {
                rows = rows+1;
            }
            equalizer = equalizer == columns ? 1 : equalizer + 1;
        }

        var newWidth = tempDocWidth * columns;
        var newHeight = tempDocHeight * rows;
        tempDoc.resizeCanvas( newWidth, newHeight, AnchorPosition.TOPLEFT );

        // Go through every comp document
        var cumulativeWidth = 0;
        var cumulativeHeight = 0;
        var equalizer = 1;
        for ( var i=0; i < tempDocsCollection.length; i++ ) {

            var compDoc = tempDocsCollection[ i ];
            app.activeDocument = compDoc;
            compLayerName = compDoc.name;

            // Duplicate comp document back to the tempdoc as a single layer...
            var compLayer = compDoc.activeLayer.duplicate( tempDoc, ElementPlacement.PLACEATEND );
            compDoc.close( SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES );
            app.activeDocument = tempDoc;
            compLayer.name = compLayerName;

            // Move comp layers side by side
            compLayer.translate( cumulativeWidth, cumulativeHeight );

            cumulativeWidth  = ( equalizer == columns ) ? 0 : cumulativeWidth  + tempDocWidth;
            cumulativeHeight = ( equalizer == columns ) ? (cumulativeHeight + tempDocHeight) : cumulativeHeight;
            equalizer = equalizer == columns ? 1 : equalizer + 1;
        }

    }

  app.preferences.rulerUnits = rulerUnits;

}

function whiteFill() {

  function cTID(s) { return app.charIDToTypeID(s); };
  function sTID(s) { return app.stringIDToTypeID(s); };

  var desc419 = new ActionDescriptor();
  desc419.putEnumerated( cTID('Usng'), cTID('FlCn'), cTID('Wht ') );
  desc419.putUnitDouble( cTID('Opct'), cTID('#Prc'), 100.000000 );
  desc419.putEnumerated( cTID('Md  '), cTID('BlnM'), cTID('Nrml') );
  executeAction( cTID('Fl  '), desc419, DialogModes.NO );

}

function selectAllLayers() {

    // Makes background layer a normal layer.
    // Otherwise it wouldn't be selected in the next step.
    var firstLayer = app.activeDocument.layers[ app.activeDocument.layers.length - 1 ];
    if ( firstLayer.isBackgroundLayer ) firstLayer.isBackgroundLayer = false;

    // Select all layers...
    var actionDescriptor = new ActionDescriptor();
    var actionReference = new ActionReference();
    actionReference.putEnumerated( charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " ), charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" ), charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" ) );
    actionDescriptor.putReference( charIDToTypeID( "null" ), actionReference );
    executeAction( stringIDToTypeID( "selectAllLayers" ), actionDescriptor, DialogModes.NO );

}

function addBlackBorder() {

  function cTID(s) { return app.charIDToTypeID(s); };
  function sTID(s) { return app.stringIDToTypeID(s); };

  var desc97 = new ActionDescriptor();
  desc97.putBoolean( cTID('Rltv'), true );
  desc97.putUnitDouble( cTID('Wdth'), cTID('#Pxl'), 2.000000 );
  desc97.putUnitDouble( cTID('Hght'), cTID('#Pxl'), 2.000000 );
  desc97.putEnumerated( cTID('Hrzn'), cTID('HrzL'), cTID('Cntr') );
  desc97.putEnumerated( cTID('Vrtc'), cTID('VrtL'), cTID('Cntr') );
  desc97.putEnumerated( sTID('canvasExtensionColorType'), sTID('canvasExtensionColorType'), cTID('Clr ') );
      var desc98 = new ActionDescriptor();
      desc98.putUnitDouble( cTID('H   '), cTID('#Ang'), 0.000000 );
      desc98.putDouble( cTID('Strt'), 0.000000 );
      desc98.putDouble( cTID('Brgh'), 0.000000 );
  desc97.putObject( sTID('canvasExtensionColor'), cTID('HSBC'), desc98 );
  executeAction( cTID('CnvS'), desc97, DialogModes.NO );

}

function dialog( compsLength ) {

    /*
    Code for Import https://scriptui.joonas.me — (Triple click to select):
    {"activeId":0,"items":{"item-0":{"id":0,"type":"Dialog","parentId":false,"style":{"varName":null,"text":"Compare Selected Comps.jsx","preferredSize":[0,0],"margins":29,"orientation":"row","spacing":10,"alignChildren":["right","center"]}},"item-1":{"id":1,"type":"EditText","parentId":0,"style":{"varName":null,"text":"4","preferredSize":[52,0],"alignment":null,"helpTip":null}},"item-2":{"id":2,"type":"StaticText","parentId":0,"style":{"varName":null,"text":"Max comps side by side:","justify":"left","preferredSize":[0,0],"alignment":null,"helpTip":null}},"item-5":{"id":5,"type":"Button","parentId":0,"style":{"varName":null,"text":"Cancel","justify":"center","preferredSize":[0,0],"alignment":null,"helpTip":null}},"item-6":{"id":6,"type":"Button","parentId":0,"style":{"varName":null,"text":"Compare","justify":"center","preferredSize":[0,0],"alignment":null,"helpTip":null}}},"order":[0,2,1,6,5]}
    */

    // DIALOG
    // ======
    var dialog = new Window("dialog");
        dialog.text = "Compare Selected Comps.jsx";
        dialog.orientation = "row";
        dialog.alignChildren = ["right","center"];
        dialog.spacing = 10;
        dialog.margins = 29;

    var statictext1 = dialog.add("statictext");
        statictext1.text = "Max comps side by side:";

    var edittext1 = dialog.add("edittext");
        edittext1.text = "4";
        edittext1.preferredSize.width = 52;

    var button1 = dialog.add("button", undefined, undefined, {name:"ok"});
            button1.text = "Compare";
            button1.justify = "center";

    var button2 = dialog.add("button", undefined, undefined, {name:"cancel"});
            button2.text = "Cancel";
            button2.justify = "center";

    // Customization

    edittext1.text = compsLength;
    edittext1.active = true;

  button1.onClick = function() {
     startCompare = true;
     maxHorizontal = parseInt( edittext1.text, 10);
     dlg.close();
  }

  button2.onClick = function() {
    dlg.close();
  }

  dialog.show();


}
```

Comment: which third party app are you using the run the script?

Comment: This looks like a good v1. Bug report - just tried it with a CMYK 300dpi document to show the front and back side of a biz card design side by side... it almost got it, but the other layer needs to be offset by the document dimensions https://gyazo.com/eddb29813a854e65548d43e3d959f57d

Comment: @ina, Alfred (for Mac). I talk a bit about that in this answer: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/63446/2332 - I prefer it mainly because as long as I have Dropbox and Alfred installed, I have my shortcuts / other familiar methods at hand. I do use a custom applescript to find the Dropbox folder though.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/0419ef12941a348624a6b1b66dafe6be

Comment: Not sure what is happening In the second video, but in the first one it looks like you select one layer comp in the beginning, so it only outputs that. What did you do to get what we see in the second video?

Comment: If you put the script in photoshop's script folder, you can run the script via that file>scripts menu without having to look for it every single time.

Comment: oops I forgot to select the layercomps i was interested in! this seems to work now

btw what do you use to manage and organize various photoshop scripts?

Comment: i think the second one was what happened when i ran it again

Comment: @ina, Definitely [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com/). It's great for managing lots of scripts of any amount really... Especially its [File Filter](https://www.alfredapp.com/help/workflows/inputs/file-filter/). I have a file filter set for both PS and AI where when I open the Alfred launcher `Ctrl+Space` and write `.ps ` or `.ai ` any following characters I write does a fuzzy search for either PS or AI scripts in specific folders I have in Dropbox. So if I download a PS script, I put it in that Dropbox folder and I can immediately search for it using `.ps ...`

Comment: Oh and I almost forgot... I got these file filters setup to open the file in PS or AI when I press enter with a file selected, like you see in the gif. You do need the Powerpack license for Alfred to use that or pretty much any of its custom automation related features. It does have keywords too if you want to give a script or anything a specific keyword to find it via the Alfred launcher or you can also give shortcut triggers too. I only give shortcuts for scripts I use a lot or where it makes sense. The file filter is excellent for those scripts you use rarely.

Comment: Just as a neat example on how amazing alfred/dropbox sync combo is... I'm on a different computer right now and didn't do anything except start the computer and if I wanted to, I could search and run that script with: `Ctrl+Space` → `.ps compare` → `Enter`. Same thing if I ever format my computer or something... I just install Dropbox and Alfred and I'm back to using the same keywords and shortcut keys...

Comment: do you also use Alfred for managing (searching through) lots of stock assets? 3d models particularly?

Comment: @ina, I don't really work a lot with 3D assets of any kind, so I don't have experience with that, but in general, I would say it's great for anything that is searchable by filename. Previewing is a little stiff though. Like if you have an image with multiple versions or maybe even a text file, if the filename isn't enough to tell you which one it is you are looking for, then you likely need to preview them. Previewing multiple files in Alfred is stiff because you have to close quick look in between. Unlike in Finder, where you can just arrow down to preview the next one.

Comment: So there definitely are situations where I just use Alfred to open a folder and use Finder or [Path Finder](https://cocoatech.com/) to do the rest. — That file filter I've been talking about is not the only way to search for files either. It's more for targetting specific folders. You can also do a more general search if you open the Alfred launcher `Ctrl+space`, press `space` to go into file search mode and then you can search and traverse folder structures using the arrow keys.

Comment: I can't talk so much about Alfred and not mention [Packal](http://www.packal.org/). It's a third party site for packal workflows and is well known among Alfred users. Obviously you can make your own Workflows too, and you should, but there are many good workflows out there, like [this one](http://www.packal.org/workflow/system-commands) I've made and shared in packal. You can also find some Workflows in the official Alfred forums, github and generally from Google.

Comment: AMAZING! i feel like i've been completely in the dark on more efficient workflows in mac

Comment: @ina, I bumped into this question again and this is a little late, but just thought I'd link the file filter workflow I talked about above: https://github.com/joonaspaakko/Photoshop-Illustrator-Script-Launcher-Using-Alfred